# Setting value in Google Script doesn't work when try to put using variable row and fixed column number

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my code, in the last line I am trying to put "Yes" in the column J. I am using row number as variable i since the row count will be different always. If I provide cell value directly like J1 then it works. Can someone please help ?

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var rowCount = sheet.getRange('A:A').getLastRow();
  var PTOEmail = "lssnihit@gmail.com";

  for(var i=2; i<rowCount; i++)
  {
    if(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() != "" && sheet.getRange(i,10).getValue() != "Yes")
      {
        var requesterName = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        var requesterEmail = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
        var startDate = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
        var endDate = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
        var sickHours = sheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
        var vacationHours = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
        var approverEmail = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
        var comStatus = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
        var mailSubject = "Leave Information for "+requesterName;
      }
  }     

        var mailBodyOK = "Hi, "+requesterName+" has requested for leave starting from "+startDate+" to "+endDate+". It contains "+sickHours+" sick hours and "+vacationHours+" vacation hours. \n"+requesterName+" has stated that communication with onsite FB manager is done and manager is fine with the leave.";

        if ( comStatus == "Informed - OK with leave")
        {
          MailApp.sendEmail( {
            to: approverEmail,
            cc: PTOEmail,
            subject: mailSubject,
            htmlBody: "<p> "+mailBodyOK+"</p>" 
          })
        }
   sheet.getRange(i, 10).setValue("Yes"); //indicates that mail is sent
}
```

Comment: Probably you have a loop issue (code that should/should not be in the loop is/is not in the loop, or your loop iteration bounds are incorrect). But, you don't explain what is actually happening vs what you expect should happen, so we can't be sure what your issue actually is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `var i` is not known at the line setting the value (outside the loop). If you need to use it this way, declare it before the loop.

Comment: Yes, it was the issue. I need to the line setting the value inside the loop. Its fixed now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for you:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=range.getValues();
  var rowCount = sheet.getLastRow();
  var PTOEmail = "lssnihit@gmail.com";
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var requesterName = vA[i][1];
    var requesterEmail = vA[i][2];
    var startDate = vA[i][3];
    var endDate = vA[i][4];
    var sickHours = vA[i][5];
    var vacationHours = vA[i][6]
    var approverEmail = vA[i][7];
    var comStatus = vA[i][8];
    var mailSubject = "Leave Information for "+requesterName;
    var mailBodyOK = "<p>Hi, "+requesterName+" has requested for leave starting from "+startDate+" to "+endDate+". It contains "+sickHours+" sick hours and "+vacationHours+" vacation hours. \n"+requesterName+" has stated that communication with onsite FB manager is done and manager is fine with the leave.</p>";var mailBodyOK = "<p>Hi, "+requesterName+" has requested for leave starting from "+startDate+" to "+endDate+". It contains "+sickHours+" sick hours and "+vacationHours+" vacation hours. \n"+requesterName+" has stated that communication with onsite FB manager is done and manager is fine with the leave.</p>";
    if ( comStatus == "Informed - OK with leave")
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail(approverEmail,mailSubject,null, {cc: PTOEmail, htmlBody: mailBodyOK})
    }
    sheet.getRange(i+1,10).setValue("Yes"); //indicates that mail is sent
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper but I need variable values for row which changes as per the value of i in the for loop. So I need to use i inplace of 9 in the second last line of the code you have commented.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back.  I put the sendEmail stuff up in the loop and I'm guessing that should be i+1.